# Why does the OrderedDict keys view compare order-insensitive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals, ordereddictionary

Why does the `OrderedDict` keys view compare order-insensitive?

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> xy = OrderedDict([('x', None), ('y', None)])
>>> yx = OrderedDict([('y', None), ('x', None)])
>>> xy == yx
False
>>> xy.keys() == yx.keys()
True
```

The OrderedDict keys view should arguably behave like an OrderedSet, but instead it behaves the same as `dict.keys` (i.e. like a usual `set`).

Same "issue" in python2:

```
>>> xy.viewkeys() == yx.viewkeys()
True
```

They are different types, (`odict_keys` is a subclass of `dict_keys`)

```
>>> type(xy.keys())
odict_keys
>>> type({}.keys())
dict_keys
```

And there is already an [order-sensitive keys comparison available](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/odictobject.c#L794) that they could have trivially used, but it's apparently only used as a [post-check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/odictobject.c#L1604) for the odict rich comparison.

Is this a design decision, or a bug?  If it's a design decision, where could I find a discussion of the justification?

Comment: If you're keen to work around this behaviour because you need to compare the orders too, you could squirt the keys out into lists and compare those: `list(xy) == list(yx)`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson or `all(x == y for x, y in zip(xy, yx))` if you want slightly lazier evaluation on python3.x

Comment: @mgilson: You'd need to check `len` too, or use `itertools.zip_longest` with a sentinel, or that will return `True` if one set of keys is a truncated run of the other keys. You can also push more work to the C layer, running a titch faster for all but the smallest runs by importing at the top `from operator import eq` and then do `len(xy) == len(yx) and all(map(eq, xy, yx))` at the test site, validating the length first then performing C level key comparisons as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @ShadowRanger -- good point.  I didn't think of that, but I should have.

Comment: Also note that other python implementations use ordered dictionaries by default ([`pypy`](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2015/01/faster-more-memory-efficient-and-more.html)).  Making `KeysView` behave differently for ordered dict than for regular dict might make their implementation more difficult (which is sometimes considered in language decisions as far as I can tell).

Comment: I posted on the Python-ideas mailing list to have more information: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-December/037472.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `OrderedDict` delegates the implementation of the various view objects to the common `dict` implementation; this remains the case even in Python 3.5 where `OrderedDict` gained a C accelerated implementation ([it delegates object construction to `_PyDictView_New`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e81189f75d04/Objects/odictobject.c#l2119) and [provides no override](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e81189f75d04/Objects/odictobject.c#l2176) for the generic view's [rich comparison function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e81189f75d04/Objects/dictobject.c#l3332).

Basically, `OrderedDict` views iterate with the same order their backing `OrderedDict` would (because there is no cost to do so), but for `set`-like operations, they act like `set`, using content equality, subset/superset checks, etc.

This makes the choice to ignore ordering make sense to some extent; for some `set` operations (e.g. `&`, `|`, `^`), the return value is a `set` without order (because there is no `OrderedSet`, and even if there were, which ordering do you use for something like `&` where the ordering may be different in each view?), you'd get inconsistent behaviors if some of the `set`-like operations were order sensitive and some weren't. And it would be even weirder when two `OrderedDict` keys views were order sensitive, but comparing `OrderedDict` views to `dict` views wasn't.

As I noted in the comments, you can get order sensitive `keys` comparison pretty easily with:

```
from operator import eq

# Verify that keys are the same length and same set of values first for speed
# The `all` check then verifies that the known identical keys appear in the
# same order.
xy.keys() == yx.keys() and all(map(eq, xy, yx))

# If you expect equality to occur more often than not, you can save a little
# work in the "are equal" case in exchange for costing a little time in the
# "not even equal ignoring order case" by only checking length, not keys equality:
len(xy) == len(yz) and all(map(eq, xy, yx))
```

Comment: "And it would be even weirder when two OrderedDict keys views were order sensitive, but comparing OrderedDict views to dict views wasn't." - but comparing OrderedDicts and dicts already has this inconsistency, leading to horrible situations where `a == b == c` but `a != c` because a and c are ordered and b isn't. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @user2357112: Yeah, I didn't say the rationale was followed consistently everywhere, just for mapping views. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything published, but I guess this logic could justify the behaviour:

If you have two dictionaries, d1 and d2, you'd expect that comparing the keys checks whether they have the same keys, right?

```
def compare_dict_keys(d1, d2):
    d1.keys() == d2.keys()
```

This function should behave the same way for any types of dictionary (and `OrderedDict` is a type of `dict`). It would seem wrong if such a function started returning `False` just because d1 and d2 are sorted.

In other words, these should all evaluate the same (and they do):

```
>>> {1:2, 3:4}.keys() == {3:4, 1:2}.keys()
True
>>> {1:2, 3:4}.keys() == OrderedDict([(3,4),(1,2)]).keys()
True
>>> OrderedDict([(1,2),(3,4)]).keys() == OrderedDict([(3,4),(1,2)]).keys()
True
```

**But `OrderedDict` is specal, isn't it?**

What `OrderedDict` does offer you is the guarantee of order when you iterate through it. The same guarantee exists for `OrderedDict.keys()`, but without breaking the compatibility with `dict`.

Comment: Note, `d1.keys() != d2.keys()` does not imply `d1.keysview() != d2.keysview()` (on python2.x).

Comment: @mgilson What is `d.keysview()`?

Comment: Argv -- I always get that backwards.  I meant that `d1.keys() != d2.keys()` does not imply `d1.viewkeys() != d2.viewkeys()`.  For a concrete example, consider `d1 = {1:1, 9:9}`  and `d2 = {9:9, 1:1}` -- Here the results of `.keys()` aren't equal, but the two unordered dicts have the same keys.

Comment: There is actually no diffrence between `{1:1, 9:9}` and `{9:9, 1:1}`. The problem with python 2 is that `dict.keys()` comparison is broken (i.e. you are not supposed to do `d1.keys() == d2.keys()` in python 2 at all, because you are shooting yourself in the foot if you do.

Comment: @zvone: It's not broken, it's just returning a `list` that copies the `dict` keys; not broken, but bad for performance and not what you typically need.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The **comparison** *is* broken, i.e. comparing them does not guarantee anything. In other words, if `a.keys() != b.keys()`, that does not tell you *anything*. It could in fact still be true that `a== b`.