# Does ordered dict return keys in order too?

Tags: python

For example:

```
my_dict = OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

If an operation to get keys i.e. `my_dict.keys()` or  `my_dict.iterkeys()` is done, is it guaranteed to return:
`['apple','banana','orange','pear']` ?

This is not explicitly mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Yes. "OrderedDict - dict subclass that remembers the order entries were added"

Comment: @AndreyT I know about the items, or iterating, my question is specifically about the .keys() or .values() methods

Comment: @DhruvPathak: and what makes you think they won't be? key-value pairs are the entries. Iterating over keys, values or items all have to use that same order. It'd be *very* surprising if that was not the case, and would have to be explicitly documented as an exception. There is no such exception in the documentation.

Comment: @DhruvPathak That would be implied by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict): "*Equality tests between OrderedDict objects are order-sensitive and are implemented as list(od1.items())==list(od2.items()). Equality tests between OrderedDict objects and other Mapping objects are order-insensitive like regular dictionaries. This allows OrderedDict objects to be substituted anywhere a regular dictionary is used.*"

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because I did not see this explicitly written in the docs, and asked to confirm, and avoid any logical exceptions like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320600/why-does-the-ordereddict-keys-view-compare-order-insensitive

Comment: @DhruvPathak: that exception is a bug; either in the documentation or in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **all** iterations are guaranteed to use the same order.

If they didn't, that'd be a very big exception that would have to be explicitly documented. The documentation contains no such exceptions.

You can always check the [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l34), explicitly linked from the top of the module documentation. You'll note that all method implementations use iteration over `self`, either directly or via `iter(self)` or `list(self)`; all these are fed by the `OrderedDict.__iter__` method, which produces keys in order:

```
def __iter__(self):
    'od.__iter__() <==> iter(od)'
    # Traverse the linked list in order.
    root = self.__root
    curr = root[1]                                  # start at the first node
    while curr is not root:
        yield curr[2]                               # yield the curr[KEY]
        curr = curr[1]                              # move to next node
```

For example, the `OrderedDict.values()` method uses those keys to map to values:

```
def values(self):
    'od.values() -> list of values in od'
    return [self[key] for key in self]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `OrderedDict` will return the keys in order.  It is worth mentioning, however, that [the keys **views** compare order insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34320600/674039) which is somewhat surprising.

Here is the 2.7 [reference python implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py) of `__iter__`, which both of `.keys` and `.iterkeys` methods will delegate to:

```
def __iter__(self):
    'od.__iter__() <==> iter(od)'
    # Traverse the linked list in order.
    root = self.__root
    curr = root[1]                                  # start at the first node
    while curr is not root:
        yield curr[2]                               # yield the curr[KEY]
        curr = curr[1]                              # move to next node
```

`self.__root` is just a list here.

*Note:* actual implementation is in C code.

Comment: I don't see a C implementation for OrderedDict in Python 2. Only Python 3 has an accelerated version.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes

Longer answer:

the implementation of the keys (and also the values) method is based upon the `__iter__` method which "Traverse the linked list in order."

```
    def keys(self):
        return list(self)

    def values(self):
        return [self[key] for key in self]
```

You can check the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py) linked in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) :